# incorrect number of dimensions output could not be returned

Tags: r, r-server

Here is my R code. **This code is deployed on machine learning server (Rserver) as web service.**

```
mydata <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
req <- POST("<<someurl>>",httr::add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"),body = bdy, encode = "json", verbose())

json <- content(req, 'text')

SpanningTree <- fromJSON(json)

df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df1 <- mydata[grep("Backup|Blocking", SpanningTree$Value),]
```

I am calling this web service (batch wise) from remote machine (c# client) but getting error on above line saying " **incorrect number of dimensions output could not be returned.**" (I don't get this error on demand ).

Even if i go to machine learning server(RServer) and call above model from r studio, error is same.

Comment: If i run above code from rstudio locally (line by line execution), i am not getting any error.

Comment: it was a mistake while posting a question.Please check now

Comment: what package are you using ? what is `SpanningTree`? I'm afraid there is not enough info in your post to help you. Please see how to create a [mcve]